# Using powershell to pull from a form and create an AD account

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Where I work, the hiring managers fill out an infopath form with the all the information needed to create the new AD account:

```
Last name
Middle Intial
last name
Assigned Phone
Office
Discription
Telephone Number.
Groups needed
```

I then need to read the form and create the AD account by hand.

I'm thinking I can create a GUI that might import the data from the form and automate the AD account creation.

Can anyone point me in the general direction where I can read how to do this?

I'm still new to Powershell but I'm willing to learn it and I'm enjoying it so far.

Thank you for any information you might share.

Doug

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do.

1. Create a standard form to have the hiring managers fill out as a .csv file (excel basically)
2. import-csv into powershell - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx
3. import-module ActiveDirectory - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378937(WS.10).aspx
4. Look up the command to make a new-ADuser - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx